How to reference HTMLElement in VueJs and it can be use by DOM Api
When I use ref ,it's return value is not Element,but a Readonly
// template
<div ref="refs"></div>

// script setup
const refs = ref<Element>()
onMounted(() => {
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          // balabala         
        }
      },
      { threshold: [0.4, 0.6] }
    )
  observer.observe(refs.value); // observer.observe need a Element type,but refs.value is not
})

enter image description here
In addition to use 'as' to force the type ,could I have other way to solve this ?
use ref ,but i faild

If the error occurs in IDE only it may be specific to it. You can try shallowRef instead which would be more correct as you don't need to make ref value deeply reactive

Ref will return the DOM element, you can cross verify your ref by using instanceof method. refs.value instanceof HTMLElement.

@EstusFlask Thanks very much,Solve this ,the type is right
